# integer increment inside pack expansion

Tags: c++

I have two functions `row` and `col`. `row` is a wrapper for `col` and should pack the return types to a tuple.

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
T col(size_t i)
{
    return T(i);
}

template<typename ...Ts>
auto row()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    return std::make_tuple(col<Ts>(i++)...); //<-- undefined behaviour
}

int main()
{
    auto m_row = row<int,int,double>(); //should expand to std::make_tuple(col<int>(0),col<int>(1),col<double(2));
    std::cout << "std::get<0>(m_row)-" << std::get<0>(m_row) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::get<1>(m_row)-" << std::get<1>(m_row) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::get<2>(m_row)-" << std::get<2>(m_row) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is the integer `i` which has to be incremented inside the expansion from 0 up to `sizeof...(Ts)`. I have considered index of the current type but this is not working if the types are not unique. I lack of other ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) can help here.  You'll have to add a layer of abstraction but you'll get a compile time back of indices.

Comment: Oh Ok Thank You I was more hoping for a simple hack but this will do it too.

Comment: `return std::tuple<Ts...>{col<Ts>(i++)...};` should do the trick. [rules 10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules)

Comment: @felix This one is genius. Only downside gcc gives `-Wsequence-point` warning (see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253).

Answer (score 0):

Using [std::index_sequence_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) we can achieve a moderately simple (but not as simple as I had hoped) solution.

As @NathanOliver mentioned, it requires a level of indirection because we need to inform a helper function of the index sequence. The top level function now looks like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>                                                         
auto row() {                                                                      
    return make_row(std::tuple<Ts...>{},                                          
            std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});                                    
}
```

So the helper function takes a default constructed `tuple` of the type requested, and the compile time sequence of integers.

All the helper needs to do now is to construct a `Tuple` using the index sequence (0, 1, ...).

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>                                      
auto make_row(Tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {                                
    return Tuple{ Is... };                                                        
}
```

Finally, to verify this does what we wanted:

```
int main()                                                                        
{                                                                                 
    auto r = row<int,int,double>();                                               
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(r), std::tuple<int, int, double>>::value);
}
```